# Partial processing of a multipart/formdata request

Tags: rest, http, multipartform-data

Is it possible to partially process a `multipart/formdata` request? I am developing a REST API wherein one of the resources is used to upload a large file. The application must take a call on processing the request based on the name of the file being uploaded, possibly sending back an alternate response if the file name fails validation.

If the application receives the large file and then performs the validation that triggers that alternate response, the time and resources used for the upload are both wasted. I prefer to preempt the upload of the actual file if the filename validation fails.

How can I implement this? I have considered the approach of first sending a request using the `HEAD` method and supplying the filename, with a subsequent upload contingent on the response to the first [HEAD] call. I would like to know if there are better alternatives.

Note: I am using Spring Boot to develop the RESTful application, although I imagine that will not significantly impact the answer I am seeking.

Comment: You generally can't send `HEAD` requests to resources that process `POST`/`PUT` requests.  Why not just define a separate REST resource that the client can send the filename to first, and if validated then upload the actual file?

Comment: If I was going with the `HEAD` request approach, I would have done exactly what you suggested. But I was trying to avoid that and see if there was a way I could process the "first" part of a multipart request which revealed the name of the file, and then decide if the server side was going to allow the upload to happen. I guess this points to a fundamental understanding too. That is, whether or not a multi part request must be fully received in order to be processed.

Comment: From HTTP's perspective, no.  An HTTP server is allowed to send a response as soon as it has one to send, even if the client is still sending the request.  Now, whether your particular HTTP server is architectured to support that, or if it requires reading the entire request before then allowing you to process it, is a separate issue.  What kind of HTTP server are you using exactly?

Comment: Tomcat (embedded, Spring Boot, defaults)